# Sort RecyclerView

Tags: android, sorting, android-recyclerview

I'm using recyclerview to show my list of ground machines. Also I have a check box widget. When check box is checked, I want to sort my list by brand of machine. In my adapter I have a method setMachine(List listMachines); which has a reference to my current list of machines. Also my sort method works fine, but when I checked my check box my list is not sorted, worst it's disappeared, and my current list of machines is zero. Can someone help me to understand why that is happening:

My RecyclerView Adapter:

```
public class ListMachineAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ListMachineAdapter.ViewHolder> {
private List<Machine> listOfMachines;
private ClickMachineItemListener selectMachine;
private View.OnClickListener showToast = new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ViewHolder vh = (ViewHolder) v.getTag();
        int position = vh.getItemPosition();
        selectMachine.onClick(position);
    }
};


public ListMachineAdapter(List<Machine> listOfMachines) {
    this.listOfMachines = listOfMachines;

}


@Override
public ListMachineAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_list_machine, parent, false);
    view.setOnClickListener(showToast);
    return new ViewHolder(view, viewType);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    Machine machine = listOfMachines.get(position);
    holder.setPosition(position);
    holder.brandMachine.setText(machine.getTypeBrand());
    holder.typeMachine.setText(machine.getTypeMachine());


}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return listOfMachines.size();
}

public void setMachine(List<Machine> listMachines){
    this.listOfMachines = listMachines; // size = 0 ??

}

public void setSelectMachine(ClickMachineItemListener selectMachine){
    this.selectMachine = selectMachine;
}
```

Also I using  Singleton to store my sort method:

```
  public class MachineManager {
    private static MachineManager instance;
    private List<Machine> listOfGroundMachines;

    private MachineManager() {
        listOfGroundMachines = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public static MachineManager getInstance() {
        return instance = (instance == null) ? new MachineManager() : instance;
    }

    public List<Machine> sortByTypeBrand() {
        Collections.sort(listOfGroundMachines, new Comparator<Machine>() {
            @Override
            public int compare(Machine lhs, Machine rhs) {
                return lhs.getTypeBrand().compareToIgnoreCase(rhs.getTypeBrand());
            }
        });
        return listOfGroundMachines;
    }
}
```

And this is my Activity:

```
public class ListGroundMachineActivity extends Activity {

    private CheckBox sortByTypeMachine, sortByTypeEngine, sortByTypeBrand, sortByYear;
    private List<Machine> listOfGroundMachines;
    private ListMachineAdapter adapter;
    private MachineManager manager;
    private ClickMachineItemListener click = new ClickMachineItemListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(int position) {
            Machine machine = listOfGroundMachines.get(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(ListGroundMachineActivity.this, MachineDetailsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(Constants.TYPE, machine.getTypeMachine());
            intent.putExtra(Constants.BRAND, machine.getTypeBrand());
            intent.putExtra(Constants.YEAR, machine.getYear());
            intent.putExtra(Constants.ENGINE, machine.getTypeEngine());
            Toast.makeText(ListGroundMachineActivity.this, machine.getTypeBrand(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_list_ground_machine);
        manager = MachineManager.getInstance();
        listOfGroundMachines = populateGroundListMachine();
        Log.i("TAG", "List size is " + listOfGroundMachines.size());
        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list_ground_machine);
        adapter = new ListMachineAdapter(listOfGroundMachines);
        sortByTypeMachine = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.sort_by_type_ground_machine);
        adapter.setSelectMachine(click);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.addItemDecoration(new HorizontalDividerItemDecoration.Builder(this)
                .color(R.color.teal).build());
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        sortByTypeMachine.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

                adapter.setMachine(manager.sortByTypeBrand());
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                Log.i("TAG 1", "List size is " + manager.sortByTypeBrand());
            }
        });
    }

    private List<Machine> populateGroundListMachine() {
        List<Machine> listOfGroundMachineOne = new ArrayList<>();
        MachineDB machineDb = new MachineDB(this);
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = machineDb.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.query(MachineDB.TABLE_GROUND_MACHINE, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
            String typeBrand = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.BRAND));
            String typeMachine = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.TYPE));
            String typeEngine = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.ENGINE));
            String year = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.YEAR));
            Machine machine = new Machine(typeBrand, typeMachine, typeEngine, year);
            listOfGroundMachineOne.add(machine);
        }
        sqLiteDatabase.close();


        return listOfGroundMachineOne;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `listOfGroundMachines` in `MachineManager` is only an empty `arraylist`:

```
private MachineManager() {
    listOfGroundMachines = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

You need to create setter for that and call the setter after this code:

```
manager = MachineManager.getInstance();
listOfGroundMachines = populateGroundListMachine();
// here
```

Comment: Thank you, I understand now :)

Answer (score 0):

The `MachineManager` `listOfGroundMachines` is an empty list. 
You call  `listOfGroundMachines = populateGroundListMachine();` in your `Activity` class. 
The list being populated with the machines is a member of `ListGroundMachineActivity` and not of `MachineManager`.